# Mapping Oracle Date to DateTime with Nhibernate 3.2

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, datetime, date

First, a simple example to describe my problem.

Model

```
public class User
{
    public virtual String UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual String UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastLoginTime { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping

```
<id name="UserID" type="AnsiString">
  <column name="p_UserID_vc" length="20"></column>
  <generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name="UserName" column="UserName_vc"  type="AnsiString">
<property name="LastLoginTime" column="LastLoginTime_d" type="DateTime">
```

table

```
create table T_User
(
    p_userid_vc         VARCHAR2(20) not null,
    username_vc         VARCHAR2(50),
    lastlogintime_d     DATE,
)
```

Now ,there are one million users in this table. I create  a oracle index in LastLoginTime.  I use query like this:

```
var list = Responsity<User>.Where(q => q.LastLoginTime <= DateTime.Now &&   
           q.LastLoginTime >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));
```

I use Nhibernate Profile to watchout the real sql string:

```
select t.p_UserID_vc
  from T_User t
 where t.lastlogintime_d >= TIMESTAMP '2012-03-19 16:58:32.00' /* :p1 */
   and t.lastlogintime_d <= TIMESTAMP '2012-03-26 16:58:32.00' /* :p2 */
```

It didn't use the index.  I think it should use 'to_date' ,so that it could use the index. How to config the mapping file?

Comment: There is no `LastLoginTime` in your table definition. What type is it? A `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: sorry, I have edited. the DBType of LastLoginTime is a DATE.I think the Nhibernate would used 'to_date' instead of 'TIMESTAMP'.but it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few reasons why it might not be using your index:

1. The datatype of `LastLoginTime` is a `DATE`, but the parameters are `TIMESTAMP`s, so it might be implicitly converting the column to a timestamp, which would mean it cannot use the index.
2. The Cost-Based-Optimizer (CBO) might be using statistics which indicate that using the index would be less efficient than not using it. For example, there might be very few rows in the table, or a histogram might tell the CBO that a large number of rows match the date range you're querying on. It's not uncommon for full table scans to outperform queries that use indexes.
3. Perhaps the statistics on the table are out-of-date, causing the CBO to make inaccurate estimates.

Do an explain plan on your query to determine what the cause is.

Note: the plan for a query that uses literal values (e.g. `TIMESTAMP '...'`) could very well be different to that for a query that uses bind variables (e.g. `p1` and `p2`). Run the explain plan for the query that is actually being executed.

Comment: Your first reason is right.The DbType of LastLoginTime is a DATE.I send the DateTime to Nhibernate,but it translated the parameters to TimeStamp.so that the DB couldn't use index.How could i modify the config-file to send DateTime directly?

Comment: I don't know how to configure NHibernate, sorry, but what you want is for it to use something like `TO_DATE('2012-03-19 16:58:32','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`...

Comment: finally, I found the real reason by this [article](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1659839).It's caused by sending Parameterized Query with the parameters of DateTime type.The oracle will change the parameter to TimeStamp instead of Date .So I send Date type parameters.

Comment: expired link, facing same problem now

Answer (score 0):

just in case if anyone is still looking for an answer, hope this helps
the fix is to configure it with proper dialect, in my case it is NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect